# Unable to unlock a page in AEM even though a admin

Tags: permissions, aem, unlock

We are using AEM 6.4.8 version.

Tried to lock a page through AEM interface as an admin and that was successfull

Tried to unlock the same page as an admin and it is not working. Unable to unlock the page eventhough I am part of admin group.

This is happening in all our environment across al projects. So seems like a instance wide issue.

Can anyone shed some light whats happening here?

Have read in many threads that admin should be able to unloack in any case. But in this scenario, thats also not working

Any specific permissions or so we need to check ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, *an* admin account won't cut it. You need *the* built-in `admin` account. As per [Adobe's help pages](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/UnlockALockedPage.html).

> The original user holding the lock does have permission to unlock the page. However, other users, **even if a member of the administrators group, DO NOT have the right to unlock pages that have been locked. Only the "admin" account has this right.**

Emphasis mine.